# How to prove that $f(x) = (x-1)/ (x+1)$ and $g(x) = x$ are ordinally equivalent on domain $[0, ∞)$?

Tags: functions, order-theory

I can see that for all $x$ and $y$, $f(x)≥f(y)$ iff $g(x)≥g(y)$. But what would the formal proof look like? Would it be by induction?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x-1}{x+1} = \frac{2}{(x+1)^2}>0$,

$\frac{d}{dx} x = 1>0$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Since both functions are monotonically increasing on the specified domain, they are ordinally equivalent to one another.

Comment: more important, $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Thus, their inverse are also strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for all $x\in[0,\infty),$ we have $x+1>0,$ so if $x,y\in[0,\infty),$ we have $$f(x)\ge f(y)\quad\iff\quad (x-1)(y+1)\ge(y-1)(x+1).$$ The idea from here is to keep manipulating through a chain of equivalent inequalities until you end up with $g(x)\ge g(y).$ Can you justify the above equivalence and take it from there?